# SwiftUI - PersonNameComponents() Can't be initialized with variables

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm using Xcode Version 12.0.1 (12A7300)

I've downloaded this code from Apple to test making a Monogram using PersonNameComponents.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/formatter/displaying_human-friendly_content

I've made a new project in Xcode to redo Monogram.swift from Apple's code.

My issue is: I can't initialize PersonNameComponents with variables in my project, yet it works just fine in Apple's project. Even if I copy the class and paste it in my project, I get the error.

The compiler error: "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments."
[compilor error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tmlcl.png)

```
struct Monogram_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    VStack {
        let sampleName = PersonNameComponents(familyName: "मिश्र", givenName: "करन")
        Monogram(nameComponents: sampleName, color: .orange)
            .padding(.bottom, 20)
        Monogram(nameComponents: sampleName, color: .blue, sideLength: 100)
            .padding(.bottom, 20)
        Monogram(nameComponents: sampleName, color: .pink, sideLength: 250)
    }
}
```

}

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty clear `PersonNameComponentsFormatter` has no initializers that takes no arguments. You probably forgot to include the custom init provided in `NamesView.swift` file in your project:

```
extension PersonNameComponents {
    init(namePrefix: String? = nil,
         familyName: String? = nil,
         middleName: String? = nil,
         givenName: String? = nil,
         nameSuffix: String? = nil,
         nickname: String? = nil,
         phoneticRepresentation: PersonNameComponents? = nil) {
        self.init()
        self.namePrefix = namePrefix
        self.familyName = familyName
        self.middleName = middleName
        self.givenName = givenName
        self.nameSuffix = nameSuffix
        self.nickname = nickname
        self.phoneticRepresentation = phoneticRepresentation
    }
}
```